# How can I create Horizontal header Recycler View like in YouTube app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a list of items and every item belongs to a category. Now I wanted to create the header with a small Recycler view which will show the list of categories.
Now I using this list in a collapsing toolbar and I only want to show this header only when the toolbar is collapsed.
I have seen this behavior in the YouTube app where it shows the Tag related to interest.
I have no idea how to attach visibility of the header recycler view with the collapsing of the toolbar.
and even I am unable to get any sample project related with this.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvgsk.jpg)

Comment: You can animate the visibility of toolbar according to y axis